# Getting an invalid reference in a range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

```
auto& kphist = this->kphist;
for (auto& it : kphist) {

    it.second.aging(); // EXC-BAD-ACCESS
    if(it.second.age > LAST_DAY){
        kphist.erase(it.first);
        continue;
    }

}
```

kphist is a private member

```
Class A{
private:
    unordered_map<int, KeyPointHistory> kphist;
}
```

The debugger shows all item in kphist is valid, how is it possible to have a bad reference inside the for loop. What possibly can go wrong?

Comment: What is `KeyPointHistory`?

Comment: Note cppreference on `std::unordered_map::erase`: *The order of the elements that are not erased is preserved (this makes it possible to erase individual elements while iterating through the container)
(since C++14)*

Comment: Don't modify the map while you're iterating over it.

Comment: @chris I'm pretty sure that still doesn't make it legal to first erase the current iterator and then try to increment it.

Comment: Don't erase elements of a container while you iterate over it.

Comment: @Brian, Of course, and the page notes that the iterator is invalidated. But even keeping the iterator valid, there's still a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference.com for `std::unordered_map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase): *References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other iterators and references are not invalidated.* Thus, you cannot use `std::unordered_map::erase()` from within a range for loop (since this will try to increment an invalid iterator).

To avoid incrementing an invalidated iterator, you can simply increment first
and then erase using the original iterator:

```
for(auto i=map.begin(),end=map.end(); i!=end; ) { // no increment here
  auto it=i++;                                    // but here instead
  if(must_remove(it))
    map.erase(it);
}
```

In fact, since `erase()` returns the iterator to the next element, you can avoid the extra iterator `it` (thanks to Hurkyl to pointing this out in a comment):

```
for(auto i=map.begin(),end=map.end(); i!=end; ) { // no increment here
  if(must_remove(i))
    i = map.erase(i);                             // but here 
  else
    ++i;                                          //  or here instead
}
```

No need to make a list of keys of elements to be erased ...

Btw, why don't you use a `std::map` (rather than an `std::unordered_map`) as your key is an `int` (which is easily orderable)? Also, why do you make a reference `kphist` of a member variable of the same name?

Comment: seems legit, but so ugly :)

Comment: @deW1 beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Why is this ugly? It's practical. Can you get a shorter version? (or how do you define beauty here?). Mind you that range-based for loops look concise (*beautiful*), but in fact are quite involved (and hence ugly?) when converted to normal code. Btw, this is definitely nicer than your proposal.

Comment: I've always seen this done as `if (remove) { i = map.erase(i); } else { ++i; }`. This style also has the advantage that it works for containers where all iterators get invalidated upon modification.

Comment: it wasn't meant as offense. your code is perfectly fine, but in my eyes a `for( auto a : b )` is optic wise more beautiful but of course not always applicable as we all know

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, that's also possible, and in fact avoids the extra iterator. I forget that `erase()` returns the iterator to the next element. I will amend my answer.

Comment: isnt `std::map` has log(n) access time and `std::unordered_map` has log(1) access time, what's the point of using `std::map` if I dont need the element sort?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot erase the contents / iterator while you iterate over it and neither should you.

Save the element index in a different container and when you're done loop through that and erase the elements you got.

> What possibly can go wrong?

Everything!

Comment: there is no need to save the indices of elements to be erase and erase them later. Can all be done in one loop. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can erase from an `unordered_map` by directly passing the iterator to the item to be erased. When you do so, `erase()` returns the subsequent iterator, so you can do something like this:

```
for (auto pos = kphist.begin(); pos != kphist.end(); ) {
       it.second.aging();
       if(it.second.age > LAST_DAY)
           pos = kphist.erase(it); 
       else
           ++pos;
}
```

As a bonus, this will probably be a bit faster than passing the key to be erased--since you're providing the iterator, it can get to the item to be erased directly rather than re-hashing the key to find the position you already knew.